# color code in X/HTML , CSS

Tags: css, xhtml, colors

In how many ways we can give color info in X/HTML, css?

**I know some**

1. Hex
2. color name
3. rgba

is there any other method?

and which method is preferred to use and which not? Please give explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three ways you mention are the only three.

I don't think a specific method is *generally* preferred, but as a developer, **I like to see hex numbers**.

I would **avoid color names** simply because if you want to know the true value of a color **you have to look it up** which is an annoyance in my workflow.

Also, hex numbers are the **most compact** way to describe a color (for most colors), so you might be saying a couple bytes of bandwidth by using hex. This **doesn't really matter**, but it's one of the only differences I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more method: the one you're missing is old RGB. RGBa includes opacity (that's the 'a', for *alpha*)--it's not the same as RGB. RGB is supported by a wide array of browsers, old and new; RGBa is supported by a narrower but significant set of browsers: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ (IE being the main holdout, as usual).

Which method you use really doesn't matter. I prefer hex from habit, but am starting to use RGB more so that I can start getting used to extending it to RGBa.

Comment: Yep. Part of CSS3 (next big thing and all that). Good article: http://24ways.org/2009/working-with-rgba-colour Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color

Comment: so should we use RFBa over hex?

Comment: No, only use RGBa when you need a partially transparent color. You *might* want to start using RGB so you are familiar with it, but you can't rely on RGBa in older browsers, so always define a fallback color--in RGB or hex (your choice).